# Resolving Expression in C++

Tags: c++

In C++, is resolving of an expression performed at compile time or it can be performed at run time also?
I am thinking of these situations as per my examples below

Compile time

```
x = 2 + 3;
```

Run time

```
x = a + b;
```

Note: Value of a and b are taken from console at run time.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the compiler. Many modern compilers perform constant folding - that is, expressions such as `2 + 3` are already resolved at compile time. However, the degree to which constant folding is applied varies per compiler; it may be really smart, or there may be none at all.

Note that expressions defined as being `constexpr` are always computed at compile time. `constexpr` expressions have certain limitations that guarantee it will be possible for the compiler to already fully evaluate the expression. At this time, the limitations appear to be pushed back in each successive update to the standard.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of the variables to be added is not **fixed** (e.g. `const int a = 5;`) at compile time, then the expression *cannot* be evaluated at compile time. In this case, because the values are coming from the command line, the expression must be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: This is slightly misleading in that if we wrote `const x = a + b; const y = x + 1;`, there will not in fact be any compile-time evaluation despite x and y being const. `const` only means we promise not to change it; it does not mean it is necessarily computable at compile time.

Comment: In C++98, I agree with you. In C++11, `constexpr` changes the landscape. In C++14, `constexpr` makes almost any non-ODR-use stuff doable at compile-time.